# Insert new row and copy the formulas from the row above at a newly added row location

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

whenever i insert new row manually, i need to copy the formulas from above row of inserted row.
i tried using below code , but dont know the error pop up.
eg:

E5=Sheet2!a1

E6=Sheet2!b1

E7=Sheet2!c1

**and when i insert new row it should show**

**E8=Sheet2!d1**

but when we do this manually on sheet by dragging row down it shows that columns remains same and row changes E5=Sheet2!a1

E6=Sheet2!a2

E7=Sheet2!a3

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range,RowsCount As Long,ws as worksheet)
    On Error GoTo EH
    ' Detect whole row changed
    If Target.Columns.Count = ws.Columns.Count Then
        ' Detect Extra Row
        If RowsCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            ' Copy Formulas and Format new row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Row > 1 Then
                Target.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
                Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
                Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        End If
        RowsCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `ak` in `ak.Column.Count`? (those `Column` instances should be `Columns` btw)?

Comment: Then you need to change the `Column` to `Columns`.

Comment: yeah i have Done and tried running it again, But still when i add new row, formula from above row is not been pasted in new inserted row.

Comment: What's `RowsCount`?

Comment: Dim RowsCount As Long ' Variable to track number of rows used in sheet

Comment: If you want to increment the column as you drag down, I'd use a different formula... not VBA. Copy/Paste formulas won't increment the column.

Comment: can you tell me the formula also , and even there in next column i have used vlookup  =SVERWEIS(ProjectMonths;Quality!B63:W67;18;1) same i need to do for to increase column ie.18 to 19 when i insert new row. it should be done simultaneously. this was my new question. first i need to solve this then i can work on vlookup also

Comment: I would use INDEX.

Comment: i tried using index not working =INDEX(Validation!B$370:W$370; **9** ). when i drag formula down, 9 remains constant, i want to make it 10 and next 11 as much i drag it down.

Comment: You can use ROW() to make that dynamic.